# Strange perspective issue in OpenGL

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

So i'm trying to zoom in and out of a sphere drawn at (0,0,0) with radius of 0.6, except once i reach Z of about -1.6, it and the axis i draw for orientation have vanished and i'm not sure why.

Here's my code for translation :

```
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glRotatef(rotX,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
    glRotatef(-rotY,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);
    help2.setText("xShift : " +xShift+ " yShift : " +yShift+ " zShift : " + zShift);
    glTranslatef(xShift,yShift,zShift);`
```

Here it is for drawing :

```
static Sphere temp = new Sphere();
temp.draw(0.6f, 100, 100);
```

And here is my pre-gl setup stuff :

```
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(50f, 1.0f, 0.01f, 1000f);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
```

Comment: Why are you doing anything other than `gluPerspective()`/`glOrtho()` on the projection stack?

Comment: That was for rotating the camara... Is it bad practice? Just tried with that not there and it causes problems

Comment: It can [mess up a few things](http://sjbaker.org/steve/omniv/projection_abuse.html).

Comment: This is not strange behavior at all. You are applying translation and rotation to your projection matrix, ***that*** is what is strange about this.

Comment: I was under the impression that if the translates and rotates are in the projection, it changes the viewpoint rather than the models?

Comment: No, that's not how the projection matrix works. You are thinking of the view matrix. GL combines that into a single matrix with the model matrix, if you use shaders you can isolate the two. While applying transformations to the projection matrix will often work for a lot of things, there are parts of the fixed-function pipeline  (e.g. vertex lighting) in OpenGL that need your transformations to be done to the appropriate matrix.

Comment: Right, so, i'll fix that after, unless its part of my problem here. Why is my draw distance tiny? I set the zFar to 1000 and i cant see 1000 into the distance, i see 1.6 at a stretch

Comment: Probably because you are translating your projection matrix. The [4th column of that matrix](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/files/gl_projectionmatrix_eq24.png) includes some math performed using the `zNear` and `zFar` values, and by translating the matrix you are messing with that.

Comment: I have no doubt you are right, except now, the sphere takes up the entire screen and more, and a translation has no effect on reducing the size or anything. What should i do then? Edit : And also, the axis dont appear when i should be able to see them. Have i gone seriously wrong somewhere then?

Comment: Edit your question to show what changes you tried. These transformations need to come ***after*** `glLoadIdentity (...)` for the ModelView matrix.

Answer (score 0):

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();

glRotatef(rotX,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
...
```

Why are you using the projection matrix here?  The projection matrix shouldn't be changed in this way.  This code wipes out the work you did with gluPerspective() and replaces it with the identity transform.

You should almost certainly be using the GL_MODELVIEW matrix here instead. Once you've set the perspective you have no reason to ever set the matrix mode to GL_PROJECTION again unless you want to modify the aspect (if you have a resize window event), the FOV, or the near or far planes.

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
```

By leaving this at the identity transform you're setting the camera at the origin looking down the negative Z axis.  Presumably your sphere is drawing at the origin as well so you're seeing the inside of it.  Try setting the initial camera position to something different, perhaps using gluLookAt()

```
gluLookat(0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
```

This puts you 3 units from the sphere on the Z axis looking at the origin.  If your sphere is drawing with a 0.6 radius then it should be visible.